# Angular-animate is not working. Animations don't get effected.

Tags: angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page, where I have three images and three links corresponding the images. I am using angular's ng-repeat to render the images. When the links are changed the images are reordered. 
I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/acQDsA6ssDQnsXJrxO54?p=preview) for the same. 
Below is the css that i have used.

```
.my-animation.ng-move {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
}

.my-animation.ng-move {
  opacity:0.5;
}
.my-animation.ng-move.ng-move-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

I am using chrome as my browser.
All I want is a 3d-transition or movement of images when they are reordered. I dont want to use any j-query plugin. 
I want to use angulars animate method. I will try and write the proper animations later but right now the problem is that i am unable to put any sort of animation to the images when the order is changed.

Just a hint how to make the animations work, or telling what i am doing wrong would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You plunkr works almost fine. There are only minor things missing, that prevent it from working well:

- You have to include `ngAnimate` in your module. Without, no animation is shown ever: `angular.module('home', ['ngAnimate'])`. It is not enough to only include it on your page.
- `move` behaves often strangely. In your case, it will only animate some of the elements. You rather work with `enter` and `leave`

Comment: Hey Nikolas. Thanks a ton for that. I missed adding the dependency. I have one question though. I am using 'move' because what I want is just reorder my images. I am not adding or removing any of the images. So, is my approach right?

Comment: move does not really work the way one expects it to. It will not animate all your objects (i could not really figure out why yet). Perhaps you should use both `move` and `enter` and `leave`.